# Transforming 2 columns subquery into 1 with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I'm having a little trouble with a specific query. Suppose you have a website like ebay, and you want to select the users that sold at least 2 objects, but which are of different types (clothes, electronics, etc.)

Here is what I came up with :

```
Select name, count(id_object) from user u,advert a where u.id_user=a.id_seller and 
a.id_buyer IS NOT NULL and 
id_object in (select o1.id_object, o2.id_object from object o1, object o2
where o1.id_object != o2.id_object and o1.type_object != o2.type_object)
group by name
having count(id_object)>1
```

The problem occur here:

```
id_object in (select o1.id_object, o2.id_object from object o1, object o2
where o1.id_object != o2.id_object and o1.type_object != o2.type_object)
```

This does not work **because I pull 2 columns from the sub select and id_object is only one.**

My second attempt involved separating the object1 and object 2 but since they need to be different, the added "in" returns nothing.

My third attempt was to UNION the results from object 1 and 2, but I wasn't able to place a restriction on the fact that the object1 has to be different from objet2.

If it helps, here is the simplified architecture of the tables :

```
Object (id_object, type_object)
Advert (id_seller, id_buyer, id_object)
User (id_user, name)
```

I also searched stackoverflow for similar problems without any success :
[MySQL: Using "In" with Multiple SubQueries?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4242184/mysql-using-in-with-multiple-subqueries)
[MySQL: Returning multiple columns from an in-line subquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1760817/mysql-returning-multiple-columns-from-an-in-line-subquery)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do this as:

```
select a.id_user
from advert a join
     object o
     on a.id_object = o.id_object
group by a.id_user
having count(distinct o.type_object) > 1;
```

Because an object can have only one type, this satisfies the criteria.  You could also add `and count(distinct o.id_object) > 1`, but that would be redundant.

If you want more user information, then you can join that table in, or use `in`, or use `exists`.

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this.

Edit: Damn forgot about that type thing, try the following.
Edit 2: We do not want the objects of same type, but different. Please try again, slowly getting ugly.
Edit 3: fixed number of occurrences

```
Select * from user where id_user in (
    Select c.id_seller from (
        Select a.id_seller as id_seller, 
               o.object_type as oject_type,
               count(*) as numOccurrences
        from adverts a, object o 
    where o.id_object=a.id_object 
    group by a.id_seller having count(*) > 1) c 
where c.numOccurrences > 1);
```

Comment: Your query works but returns me the name of a user that only sold the same type twice. I am trying to see why this happens because your group by seems fine

Comment: you are completely right, edited again, hopefully better now :-)

Comment: There is some issue with this part : 
`Select a.id_seller as id_seller, o.object_type as oject_type from adverts a, object o where o.id_object=a.id_object group by a.id_seller having count(*) > 1`

When I remove the group by, I get the sellers with all the categories they sold. So far so good. But when I apply the group by seller, he picks the seller ID but only 1 type of object. He doesn't keep the second one. So c.object_type is = to 1 which doesn't work.
Putting =1 instead of >1 works, but i'm wondering if it will work for every case I need?